# Client only wants to use GTM on Careers section of website. Will that limited use be viable?

Tags: google-tag-manager, zone

Can Google Tag Manager be used on just one section of a website, such as Careers section?

Answer (score 0):

Why not!

but it would be advisable to have GTM loaded on all pages but keep your trigger running only on careers pages for a particular tag.

Consider advocating for the future use of GTM even if the client is not interested today.
I strongly advise collecting Analytics Tags through GTM.